# How to check a datetime string stored in a MySQL field against now without seconds precision in a Python script?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have created a scheduler based on a systemd service triggered with a timer. A Python script is triggered every minute and does the following tasks:

1. Connect to a database Select all active schedules
2. Check if field 'execution_date' is now
3. Trigger an action if the timing is right

It seems that my comparison between 'now' and the DateTime field value retrieved from the database is not working properly. In fact, DateTime is stored with second in the database field, but I don't want/need seconds precisions, I just need to check "now" Year, month, day, hour, and minute.

For example:

> ```
> 2021-02-10 07:20:00 in database should be considered the same as 2021-02-10 07:20:18  
> 2021-02-10 07:20:00 in database should NOT be considered the same as 2021-02-10 07:21:00
> ```

**MySQL table**

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------------------+
| id | status | type    | execution_date        | 
+----+------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | X      | foo     | 2021-02-10 07:20:00   |
+----+------------------+-----------------------+
|  2 | Y      | bar     | 2021-02-10 08:23:00   |
+----+--------+---------+-----------------------+
```

**Python script**

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor
from mysql.connector import Error

def date_is_now(date_str):
    date_current = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_compare = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    
    if date_current == date_compare:
        return True
    else:
        return False

connect = mysql.connector.connect(user='db_user', password='password',host='XX.XX.XX.XX',database='db')
query = "SELECT * FROM schedule_table WHERE status = 'X'"
cursor = connect.cursor(dictionary=True)   
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall() 

logger.debug("{} schedules are active".format(len(result)))

for schedule in result:
    if schedule['type'] == 'foo' and date_is_now(schedule['execution_date']):
        logger.info("Schedule action is being triggered")
```

How to compare between now and date stored in the database without seconds precision?

Comment: whenever comparing datetimes, rather than thinking in terms of them being "equal" , think of them is falling in a range.  As an example,  something `08:15`   is   `>=  08:15:00.000` and `< 08:16:00.000`  , and as another example,  for datetimes "in February 2021" ,   `dt >= '2021-02-01` AND 1dt < '2021-03-01`.    if you want to do equals comparisons, then both values will need to be truncated, formatted, to  make them equivalent precision. my personal preference is to let the precision be what it is, and do the range comparison

Answer (score 0):

The normative pattern for comparing datetimes is to do range comparisons rather than equals comparison.

To check if execution_date is in the same minute as NOW(),  we can use expressions to derive the start and end of the range

Consider:

```
 SELECT NOW()
      , DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE AS _range_start
      , DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AS _range_end
```

We can use expressions in the WHERE clause in compare to bare datetime column:

```
SELECT t.execution_date
     , ... 
  FROM mytable t 
 WHERE t.execution_date >= DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE
   AND t.execution_date  < DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
 ORDER
    BY t.execution_date
```

If we don't want to filter rows, but return rows and just "flag" which rows fall in a datetime range, we can use expressions in the SELECT list...

```
SELECT t.execution_date
     , CASE 
         WHEN t.execution_date >= DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m') + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE
          AND t.execution_date  < DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
         THEN TRUE
         ELSE FALSE 
       END AS is_now 
     , ...
  FROM mytable t 
 WHERE ...
 ORDER BY ...
```

---

NOTE: We don't have to use database NOW(). We could supply a value (properly formatted) in place of NOW().

Comment: Question is about Python implementation, not SQL

Comment: @donmelchior:  question is tagged "mysql"; question title "MySQL field"; this answer illustrates the "range comparison" pattern recommended in the comment on the question. implement whatever you need. This answer is intended to illustrate an implementation of range comparisons for datetime. (Personally, i would not pull back rows from the database that i know will not be needed. The "select all rows" and then filter on the client works for small sets, but that pattern does not scale.)  My comment on the question holds for Python... use range comparisons in place of equals comparison.

Answer (score -1):

A quick'n dirty solution might be to convert both datetime to string and check for equality (see below). As mentionned, this might not be the cleanest solution regarding date paradigm.

**Python script**

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor
from mysql.connector import Error

def date_is_now(date_arg):
    # See change above
    date_current = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    date_compare = date_arg.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    
    if date_current == date_compare:
        return True
    else:
        return False

connect = mysql.connector.connect(user='db_user', password='password',host='XX.XX.XX.XX',database='db')
query = "SELECT * FROM schedule_table WHERE status = 'X'"
cursor = connect.cursor(dictionary=True)   
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall() 

logger.debug("{} schedules are active".format(len(result)))

for schedule in result:
    if schedule['type'] == 'foo' and date_is_now(schedule['execution_date']):
        logger.info("Schedule action is being triggered")
```